# TypeScript strange type behavior on extends in generic

Tags: typescript

```
interface empty{

}
type IfExtends<T, B, Y, N> = T extends B ? Y : N
let a: IfExtends<keyof empty, never, number, string> /// type never
let b: keyof empty extends never?number:string       /// type number
```

In my opinion generic type `IfExtends` is equal to the type of b's `extends` statement.
But type of a is never and b is number(extends true).
Why?

Comment: I think ```b``` type resolves correctly. The problem is no matter what combination of types you pass as ```T``` and ```B```, in case when one of ```T``` and ```B``` equals to ```never```, it always return ```never``` as result of ```IfExtends```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of applying a [distributive conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) type to `never`. If a distributive conditional type is applied to a union, the result will be a union of applying that conditional type to each constituent of the union:

```
type IfExtends<T> =  T extends number ? "Y" : "N"
type A = IfExtends<number | string> // = IfExtends<number> | IfExtends<string> = "Y" | "N"
```

So what does this have to do with `never`? We can get a hint if we try to union `never` with any other type:

```
type X = never | number // just number, never is omitted
```

`never` is the empty union, ie the union with no constituent. Adding it to any other union will make it melt away because of this.

Because it is the empty union, when distributing over it, the conditional type actually never get evaluated, since there are no constituents in the union to apply it to, and we just get `never` regardless of any condition in the conditional type

Using the actual inlined version does not produce the same result as distributivity only happens over naked type parameters, `T` is a naked type parameter, `keyof empty` is not.

You can disable distributivity by encasing `T` in a tuple type:

```
type IfExtends<T, B, Y, N> = [T] extends [B] ? Y : N
let a: IfExtends<keyof empty, never, number, string> /// also numberkeyof empty
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAggWwA5gJ4G8BQ+AvvjhigJIwCiAHpCACYDOAPACoA0yAQtwJrcAcgD5kAXmQBtdgF1U9CE2bSe8gPzJ+yAFzIh+ADYQwyOHqp0GLVgGsI2APYxUmHNxAQAbtA8BXNAAjX2RmMChQAHMxAHo4s0NmR2QQAOCoeycXdCxsZCMTZEC9TOdXXIVrFU8fKHVUoOgdMIiQSOQOoA)